# Image won't responsively fit width of container div

Tags: html, css

Even after using `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%` on the `img` element, the width a noticeable bit of white-space on the right. Why isn't it filling up the container?

It looks like max-height works perfectly; my thoughts is that this white space is due to the size of the actual image? Is there anyway to fill up the container responsively?

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.front-side  {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.back-side {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
  <div class='front-side'>
    <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='back-side'>
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

Comment: Well that was easy. Can you explain why that works, but max-width doesn't? Because the max-width property essentially says the image width cannot be bigger than 100% of the parent element, am I incorrect? So shouldn't it work? @tech2017

Comment: Nevermind, it's explained below. @tech2017

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }` - using **max** on both of them means that as soon as one value is hit, it will stop. It's similar to using `background-size: contain;` instead of `cover`.

Changing it to `img { width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }` should fix this, as it will make it 100% width, but prevent it from overextending the Y-axis:

Note your images aren't exactly a 3:4 ratio, so when the `max-height` gets hit (400px), the width gets stuck at 282.59px when using `max-width` (because you're telling the browser that "I want this **no more** than 300px wide" not "I want this image to be 300px wide".

All this said, I'd consider recropping your images to be the ratio you want so they don't stretch (which the solution I provided will make them slightly wider than they should be, distorting them a little)

edit: Alternatively you can drop the `max-height: 100%;` and instead set an `overflow-y: hidden;` on the parent to do a kind of "faux crop"

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* .flipcard {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 2s;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #c4c4c4;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: pink;
} */

/* .flipcard:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
} */

.front-side  {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  position: relative;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.back-side {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
/*   transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden; */
/*   position: absolute;
  top: 0; */
  border: 3px solid green;


}
```

```html
<!-- <div class='flipcard'> -->
  <div class='front-side'>
    <img src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='back-side'>
    <img src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
  </div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the object-fit css property.

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Would do the job, fill the parent container keeping ratio, and eventually crops image. Image has to have a size btw.

[Object-fit CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

```css
html, body {
  background: #f2edea;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.front-side  {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.back-side {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
 }
```

```html
  <img class="front-side" src='https://pre00.deviantart.net/4121/th/pre/i/2018/059/6/7/brigitte_by_raikoart-dc4kzas.png'>

<img class="back-side" src="https://img00.deviantart.net/e0ec/i/2017/297/8/c/mercy_by_raikoart-dbrm54b.png">
```

Don't even have to use div

Regards

Comment: For reference, note the current [browser compatibility of `object-fit`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).